# In the sentence "they were extremely well made", is the "made" a noun or participle?

Tags: verbs

In the sentence "they were extremely well made", is the "made" a noun or participle?
Could the "made" be a noun?
Thank you very much!

Comment: No, not a noun. "Well-made" is actually a verb-centred compound adjective (note the hyphen) where "well" is an adverb and "made" is a verb past participle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a participle. 'Well' is an adverb modifying 'made'. Consider also:

> The were extremely well painted/decorated.

You couldn't replace the verb form with a noun, but you **could** with an adjective if you removed 'well' also.

> They were extremely flat/old.